# Use PDF.js offline

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

Is it possible to use PDF.js without having the website online? I'm trying to do a simple offline website that reads pdf using pdf.js but it won't work without being online.

Anyone could help?

Comment: Works for me offline in Firefox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes absolutely you can use it offline. Download the latest version [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download).

Now extract the zip file and put it on a server(use xampp/wamp/lamp or any other localhost) **because the worker is not enabled for file:// urls.**

To show the pdf files traverse to **web/viewer.html** from the localhost and it should load its default pdf.

**As to the question about how to show your pdf's use:** `viewer.html?file=relative/path/to/your/pdf`

Say for example inside the web folder(the one in which viewer.html is there) of your pdf.js you create a directory say named `pdfFiles` and in it you add a pdf named say `mypdf.pdf` in it then to display it use: `viewer.html?file=pdfFiles/mypdf.pdf` and it will display it.

**Look [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2496) for more details on how to dynamically assign PDF file paths to the viewer.** If you have any other queries let me know. I have used pdf.js offline and it works wonderfully on almost all the browsers I know.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain in comment. Because I have tried this and it is working.

Comment: "put it on a server" is the opposite of "offline"