# PDF not showing on visitors browser

Tags: pdf, browser, href

I have a webpage (http://optiswissopen2015.ch/page/noticeboard) with some PDFs on it. All of them are linked the same way. But on some browsers (IE8 for sure) they are shown as text instead of open a pdf viewer.

```
<a href=" /files/Noticeboard/1436883318_sism2015.pdf"
          download runat="server" class="button color3">
```

My first thought was, that they may have a problem in the header. But converting them to .ps and back doesn't help.

What can I do, that they open right with all browsers? 
As a last option, I could ZIP them :-(

Comment: Indeed strange: if I type this url: http://optiswissopen2015.ch/files/Noticeboard/1436883318_sism2015.pdf into Safari on my Mac, Safari thinks its a txt file. I think it maybe something on the server end. If I had the time, I would "manually" open a port 80 to the server, issue a GET request and look at the response. (The other URL is fine, and your PDF is fine too - Safari does not look inside the PDF to decide what to do. If it is told that the file extension is pdf, it opens a pdf viewer).

Comment: They are all on the same server. Should they not have all the same html header?

Comment: Depends what the server does. I tried doing GETs using telnet, but the server wants POST - do you know how to do HTTP client requests using telnet? If so, do a POST request on a working and "broken" pdf and see what you get.

Comment: Not yet. But I will find out and try. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Have you tried to remove empty spaces. On the link you posted I see many empty spaces for the href tag.

Comment: The issue is solved for the moment by storing the files on a different server. But I'm still interested in the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the the issue is in the file content type returned for some PDF files on your server. To verify it use **curl -i [url]** or **wget -S [url]** or this [online tool](http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi).

For example, 1436883318_sism2015.pdf [returns](http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi?URL=http://optiswissopen2015.ch/files/Noticeboard/1436883318_sism2015.pdf) (incorrect):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "[omitted]"
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 14:15:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 1188394
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2015 17:19:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
```

And anmedleguide.pdf returns the correct header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2015 17:21:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Jul 2015 13:07:01 GMT
ETag: "[omitted]"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 932698
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: Where is this header generated? Does the server parse the file and decide how to make the header?

Comment: I suppose it is the handler in .htaccess file. 
You should have some string like this:

AddType application/pdf .pdf

in the folder with your PDF file so it will serve .pdf files with "application/pdf" content type. See http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/pdf-cookies-headers-rewrites.html and http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/ for more details

Comment: no, server is not parsing PDF files but just checking their filenames to decide what is the content-Type should be returned in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and integrate **pdf.js**.

I opened up your page in mozilla and the all the pdf's are being displayed nicely(**Mozilla Firefox by default opens up a pdf in pdf.js**). So you can integrate it in your website and get to display the pdf's in the same manner irrespective of the browser.

**On the link below I have explained how to set-up pdf.js easily.** (Just use your actual server instead of localhost mentioned there.)

Look [on this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851939/use-pdf-js-offline/31247079#31247079)

**It will take only a few minutes to set-it up** and the pdf issue will vanish for sure.

Comment: Using pdf.js would be a workaround. I will have a look at it.
The issue is solved for the moment by storing the files on a different server. But I'm still interested in the source of the problem.