# how to use pdf.js or viewerJS to display pdf in browser

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

i need a tuto about using pdf.js or viewejs to view pdf via browser. I found [viewerjs.org](http://viewerjs.org/)  but it doesn't help.
Any help thx in advance.

Comment: Using pdf.js is very simple. Look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851939/use-pdf-js-offline/31247079#31247079](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851939/use-pdf-js-offline/31247079#31247079). In this question I have shown how to use it offline. But to use it online just do the same on an actual server.

Comment: thx for ur answer. i extracted the zip file and put it on my tomcat server.  but when i do : viewer.html?file=file:////X.Y.Z.T/mydocs/mydoc.pdf  my pdf document doesn't appear. but if i call only viewer.html the document 'compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf'  (coming with viewerjs )  is shown automatically. My first qst is how to display my own document from my server, second does pdf.js work with google crome too. thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Check out my answer here to know on how to show your pdf(use relative path). And yes it will work on chrome and almost all other famous browsers.

Answer (score 1):

**Try out pdf.js as it is very simple.** Download the latest version [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download).

To show the pdf files traverse to `web/viewer.html` and it should load its default pdf.

**As to the question about how to show your pdf's use:** `viewer.html?file=relative/path/to/your/pdf`.

Say for example inside the `web folder`(the one in which viewer.html is there) of your pdf.js you create a directory say named `pdfFiles` and in it you add a pdf named say `mypdf.pdf` in it then to display it use: `viewer.html?file=pdfFiles/mypdf.pdf` and it will display it.

**Almost all browsers are supported. Look [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support) to know more about which all browsers are currently being supported.**

Comment: yeah i red it and i tried it. but i don't get my doc pdf. i get error msg 'missing PDF relative/path/mypdf.pdf....'  my pb is that my docs are in an other server, say for example 10.0.11.10/pdffiles/mypdf.pdf.  also i did the same for google chrome but i doesn't work. any help thanx

Comment: You can't do that by default. But it is possible. Check this [link](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-xhr).  [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) could be a good solution for it.

Comment: i follow the instructions but i don't get what i am looking for. i have docs in a server x and i want to put them in an internal web application (jee) deployed in other server y. (to read these docs on a browser). i extract the viewer zip (web and built ) into webapp of tomcat, and i call web/viewer.html?file=x/docs/mypdf.pdf but i dont get it. help plz

Comment: By default you cannot view files of another server using pdf.js. So when you pass query like:`web/viewer.html?file=x/docs/mypdf.pdf` it will not be able to fetch the pdf file sitting on another server x. Only the pdf's in that server can be viewed, but it is possible try out CORS as suggested in the comment above.

Comment: If your server x is online then an easier way could be using google doc viewer api. Try googling about it and a lot of tutorials will be available on how to use it.

Comment: Try `https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=full\path\to\pdf` give your full path of the pdf for example(it is online try it): `https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf`. Also a good thing is you do not need to put any thing of this viewer on your server. It will automatically fetch the pdf from your specified server and show it to you.

Comment: actually thanks for your answer and your interacting. I can't use google doc viewer because my server is not online. It is an internal web application.  thx

Comment: Happy to help :) In case I find any other way view pdf sitting on another server that is offline I will surely come back here and let u know.